# Why don't they remove negative hosts from the Trill symbiont like Joran?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

DS9 "Facets":

> DAX: The zhian'tara is a ritual where joined Trills get a chance to
>   actually meet their previous hosts.
>
> KIRA: Meet them? How?
>
> DAX: That's where you come in. If you don't mind, I'd like to borrow
>   your bodies for a few hours.
>
> O'BRIEN: What do you mean borrow our bodies?
>
> DAX: If you agree to participate, the **memories of one of my previous
>   hosts will be temporarily removed from the symbiont and imprinted onto
>   you.** You essentially become one of my hosts for the duration of the
>   ritual.
>
> BASHIR: And how is this accomplished?
>
> DAX: **The memories are transferred telepathically by a Guardian.**

I would think dying trill would be honored to do such a service to keep the symbionts purer and ethical, at least to some degree. It'd also give the ones who never got to host somebody a chance to join even if briefly with a negative host. They could set certain parameters like physical violence, murder, cruelty, rape, etc.

Wouldn't it be easy enough to transfer a negative host like Joran to a person who is on the verge of death to get rid of such a negative host who is a murderer?

Comment: Also, that negative host would be effectively reborn into the body of the carrier of the memories. Which in itself would be unethical.

Comment: There's no in-series answer to this question, and not a lot of evidence from which to speculate. All we have is the fact that they don't. I'm voting to close.

Comment: We [don't close questions just because there is no canon answer](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/3014/5184).

Answer (score 2):

That would probably have a negative effect on the Symbiont in the long run. If it was that simple to remove the essence of a previous host, that is probably what they would have done to Joran. They already went to a lot of trouble to cover him up.

Concealing the memories of Joran was traumatic enough to Dax to begin with. If that's the process they choose it was probably because it was the one that would cause the least damage to the symbiont.

Comment: Do you have any evidence of your assertions?

Comment: But weren't they reluctant to force Curzon to return to Dax. If they were such concerns about negative effects they would have made more of an effort to return those memories.